# Stapled old and new passports

Tags: visas, passports, canada, europe, pakistani-citizens

I renewed my passport and old one is expired.
My company stapled both of them. Old passport scan page is having stapled marks. Can I get visa for Europe and Canada? What impact for this things.

I have Pakistani passport.

Answer (score 4):

**I would suggest you separate them.** While stapling them together is "allowed" (the old passport is expired and invalid anyway, and staple marks on the back cover of a new passport are not material damage), there is generally no point to submitting old passports, since records are electronic these days.

The only reason you might need an old passport is if it contains valid visas *and* the country you are going to accepts visas in expired passports, but it doesn't sound like this is the case.  And even if it was, there's still no need to physically staple them together.

Comment: @Suliman Please accept the answer (click the tick mark next to it) if it answered your question!